# ansible-inventory __ansible_unsafe variables

Tags: ansible

Can anyone please explain to why a variable can sometimes be wrapped in `__ansible_unsafe` in `ansible-inventory` output?

At the same time if I enable YAML output format I get a clean output without this `__ansible_unsafe` wrapping.

And how do I get rid of this in my output?

My `ansible --version` is 2.15.2

Thank you!

I am running a simple command like

```bash
ansible-inventory --list -i hosts
```

Tried setting `allow_unsafe_lookups` to `True`. Didn't help.

Comment: Show us an example. Are there any values marked as `!unsafe` in your inventory or var files?

Comment: "_And how do I get rid of this in my output?_", why would that be necessary?

Comment: I'm trying to parse the output and these ruins it for me.

Comment: No, never used this 'unsafe' feature. As a matter of fact I have a parser  script that used to work but after one of ansible upgrades it stopped working as data output of ansible-inventory changed with those ansible_unsafe markers. I know what data is there, no passwords. So I just need it to work as before. And another thing I can't seem to understand is why only some variables are marked this way. Because not all of them are like that. I can seem to understand the logic behind this mechanism. Some variables that are set in the same way in an inventory file aren't marked . That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Why a variable can sometimes be wrapped in `__ansible_unsafe` in `ansible-inventory` output?***

Let's have a look into the following minimal reproducible example.

It is assumed that there is according [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) under `group_vars` a file `all` (`cat group_vars/all`) with [unsafe strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings), containing a password with special characters

```yaml
PASSWORD: !unsafe Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!
```

and an inventory file `example.com` with content of

```ini
[test]
test1.example.com
test2.example.com
test3.example.com
```

Then, a call

```bash
ansible-inventory --list --inventory example.com
```

will result into an output of

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "test1.example.com": {
                "PASSWORD": {
                    "__ansible_unsafe": "Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!"
                }
            },
            "test2.example.com": {
                "PASSWORD": {
                    "__ansible_unsafe": "Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!"
                }
            },
            "test3.example.com": {
                "PASSWORD": {
                    "__ansible_unsafe": "Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "test",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "hosts": [
            "test1.example.com",
            "test2.example.com",
            "test3.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```bash
ansible-inventory --list --inventory example.com --yaml
```

into

```yaml
all:
  children:
    test:
      hosts:
        test1.example.com:
          PASSWORD: Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!
        test2.example.com:
          PASSWORD: Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!
        test3.example.com:
          PASSWORD: Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!
    ungrouped: {}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. Yaml output format does remove those. But I would really like to keep json format if it is at all possible.

Comment: But the question is why? What would be the reason for that? And how do you like to have a JSON parser handle a string like `Th{'s:}s:MyP4ssw0rd!`? What should the parser do with the `{`, `:`, `'`? Maybe, escape them into something like `\{`, `\:`, `\'`, which is then also unwanted as the string doesn't stay "as is"?

Comment: I know what kind of data is there. So I am sure that there will be no characters like that. It's just some server inventory stuff.